# Endless reload with browserSync and gulp-connect-php

Tags: php, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-connect-php

I finally got around to build my own task runner but I'm stuck on a feature I really need, namely browserSync but I use php with XAMPP.

The problem: terminal keeps telling me "PHP server not started. Retrying...".

Since I'm new to all this I can't seem to figure out why the server's not connecting. Please help?

Here is my code:

```
// Required tasks
var gulp = require('gulp'),
   connect = require('gulp-connect-php'),
   browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
   reload = browserSync.reload;


// Php Server Tasks
gulp.task('connect', function() {
   connect.server({
      base: './',
      port: 8010,
      keepalive: true
   });
});


// Browser-Sync Tasks
gulp.task('browser-sync',['connect'], function() {
   browserSync({
      proxy: '127.0.0.1:8010',
      port: 8080,
      open: true,
      notify: false
   });
});


// Watch Tasks
gulp.task ('watch', function(){
   gulp.watch('src/sass/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
   gulp.watch('src/js/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
   gulp.watch('./templates/**/*.php', ['html']);
});


// Default
gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't remember where this solution popup but thought I'd share the code as it just may help someone else:

To be clear: I no longer make use of gulp-connect-php.

```
// BROWSER-SYNC TASKS
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        proxy: 'localhost/path/to/the/files',
        open: true,
        notify: false
    });
});
```